# Using the ABC-conjecture

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have to answer the following question:

Let $a,b,c \in \mathrm{Z}_{\geq3}$, use the ABC conjecture to show (we suppose that the conjecture is true) that $x^ay^b-z^c=1$ has finite solutions for $x,y,z \in \mathrm{N}$.

What I dit was the following:

Take $\alpha=x^ay^b , \beta=1$ and $\gamma = z^c$. Then we need to show that $\alpha= \beta + \gamma $ has finite solutions.

$rad(\alpha \beta \gamma) = rad(xyz) \leq xyz$

$z< (x^ay^b)^{1/c} \leq (x^ay^b)^{1/3}$ (because c>3)

Thus $rad(xyz) < xy (x^ay^b)^{1/3}$

If $\epsilon=0.1$ then $rad(xyz)^{1+\epsilon}<x^{1.1+\frac{1.1a}{3}}y^{1.1+\frac{1.1b}{3}}<x^ay^b$

Thus from the ABC-conjecture we know that there are finite solutions.

Is this correct? And if so why, because I don't understand the conjecture very well and I would like to understand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct.

To understand the ABC-conjecture, you could start with a recent overview http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.2974. Numerical evidence is shown in chapter 7 of the following  thesis https://openaccess.leidenuniv.nl/bitstream/handle/1887/25833/07.pdf?sequence=12.